# Sum of exponent of jump times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

I have the following question. I have a random variabele that is the sum of the exponent of the jumping times $T_i$ of a Poisson process $N(\cdot)$ with parameter $\lambda$.

Say:

$$B(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} e^{-r (t - \ T_i)} $$

I want to know $\mathbb{E}[B(t)]$. I can condition on $N(t)$ to see that $\mathbb{E}[B(t)] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[B(t)|N(t)=k]\mathbb{P}[N(t)=k]$. Where $\mathbb{P}[N(t)=k] = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$ is a Poisson distribution of parameter $\lambda t$.

To understand the problem I first calculated $\mathbb{E}[B(t)|N(t)=1]$, where since we condition on having one jump the jump is uniformly distributed:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[B(t)|N(t)=1]&= \int_0^t \mathbb{P}(T_1=s)e^{-r(t-s)}ds \\
&= \int_0^t \frac{1}{t} e^{-rt}e^{rs}ds \\
&= \frac{e^{-rt}}{t} \int_0^t e^{rs} ds \\
&= \frac{1}{e^{rt}} \left[ \frac{e^{rs}}{r} \right]_0^t \\
&= \frac{1}{te^{rt}} \left( \frac{e^{rt}}{r} - 1 \right) = \left( \frac{1}{tr} - \frac{e^{-rt}}{t} \right)
\end{align}

Which looks like it makes some sense. I know that the joint distribution of the jump times. Have a joint density distribution of $f(t_1,...,t_n)= \frac{n!}{t^n} 1_{(0 \leq t_1 \leq ... \leq t_n \leq t)}$ so the expected value generalised to some n would look like:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[B(t)|N(t)=n] &= \int_0^t ... \int_0^t f(t_1,...,t_n) \sum_{i=1}^n e^{-r(t-t_i)} dt_1 ... dt_n \\
&= \int_0^{t_2} ... \int_{t_{n-2}}^t \frac{n!}{t^n} \sum_{i=1}^n e^{-r(t-t_i)} dt_1 ... dt_n
\end{align}

This I am not so sure how to evaluate. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325035/poisson-processes-and-its-arrival-times/2327394#2327394 about the elementary but powerful result in solving this kind of symmetric functionals of Poisson arrival time. In your calculation of the expectation, the argument of the uniform pdf should be the same as dummy variable in the integral, and thus it must be integrated rather than being pulled out as a constant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It was this kind of question I was looking for but couldn't find. I am not sure what you mean that the argument of the uniform pdf should be the same as the dummy variable in the integral. Are you talking about the first or the second case? Because this is already the case is it not? In the first case the dummy argument s is uniform in [0,t].

Comment: Would the answer be:
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{E}[B(t)] &= \sum_k \mathbb{E}[B(t)|N(t)=k]\mathbb{P}[N(t)=k] \\
&= \sum_k \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=0}^{k} e^{-r(t-T_i)}]\mathbb{P}[N(t)=k] \\
&= \sum_k k \mathbb{P}[N(t)=k] \mathbb{E}[e^{-r(t-T_1) }] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[N(t)] \mathbb{E}[e^{-r(t-T_1) }] \\
&= \lambda t \left(\frac{1}{rt} - \frac{e^{-rt}}{rt} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{\lambda}{r} - \frac{\lambda e^{-rt}}{r} \right )
\end{align}

Comment: If you dummy variable in the integral of expectation is $s$, then the pdf of uniform will be $\displaystyle \frac {1} {s}$ in the integral rather than $\displaystyle \frac {1} {t}$.

Comment: But if we condition to having one jump in the interval $[0,t]$ then the time of this jump is uniformly distributed in $[0,t]$ right? So the probability of the jump happening at time $s \in [0,t]$ is $\frac{1}{t}$. I'm sorry if I am not following you correctly.

Comment: Sorry I misread the previous equation. I just quite out of sync these days lol.